# GraphQL Client is retuning null data in C#

Tags: .net, graphql, json.net, jsonserializer, graphql.net

I have a query defined at server side as

```
public TradeQuery(ITradeService tradeservice)
    {
        Name = nameof(TradeQuery);
        Field<ListGraphType<TradeType>>("trades", resolve: r => { return tradeservice.GetTrades(); });
    }
```

when I call if from GraphiQL client I am getting proper response.
Request from GraphiQL is

```
{
  tradeQuery {
    trades {
      id
      price
      quantity
     
    }
  }
}
```

and getting response as

```
{"data": {
    "tradeQuery": {
      "trades": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "price": 600,
          "quantity": 600
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "price": 100,
          "quantity": 100
        }]}}}
```

But When I tried to call same query using `GraphQLHttpClient` it is returning as null
In below code I am getting null values in `availableTrades` object.

```
 string apiEndpoint = "https://localhost:44342/graphql";

            var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(new GraphQLHttpClientOptions { 
                EndPoint = new Uri (apiEndpoint)
            }, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

            var tradeQuery = @"{
                              tradeQuery{
                               trades {
                                id
                                price
                                quantity}}}";
            GraphQLRequest graphQLRequest = new GraphQLRequest(tradeQuery);
            var tradeQueryResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<TradeQuery>(graphQLRequest);
            var availableTrades = tradeQueryResponse.Data.Trades;
```

Response type `TradeQuery` object defined as below

```
 public class TradeQuery
        {
            public List<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
        }
```

Can you please guide what could be wrong?

Comment: it is working fine in Insomnia. No Auth implementation

Comment: I think there is a problem in desterilizing json. It worked when I use SendQueryAsync(dynamic). Do you know how can we avoid using dynamic and get it into required object.

Answer (score 3):

Incase anyone else is having this issue, I spent hours today trying all different combinations of deserializing the result from the query and using dynamic was the only way to return anything. I eventually found a fix by doing the following.

### Prerequisites

You will need two nuget packages for this to work correctly:

1. GraphQL.Client.Abstractions
2. GraphQL.Client.Serializer.SystemTextJson;

Instead of using `new GraphQLHttpClient(apiEndpoint, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());`

Use `new GraphQLHttpClient(apiEndpoint, new SystemTextJsonSerializer());`

### Query Format

You will need to format your query by giving it an alias like I have done here. I have a query called **fakeLogin** but by prepending **data:** I have now giving the result of this query an alias of data.

```
GraphQLRequest loginRequest = new GraphQLRequest
{               
    Query = @"
    {
        data:fakeLogin
        {
            token
        }
    }"
};
```

### Sending Query and Consuming result

Now that your request is created you now need to send the query in the following format:

```
LoginToken responseData = _graphQlClient.SendQueryAsync(loginRequest, () => new { Data = new LoginToken()}).Result.Data.Data;
```

Comment: Only thing that worked in .Net 6 thank you. It isn't very clean though.

Comment: "GraphQL.Client.Abstractions" is definitely needed, without that , the deserialization won't work.  also you can use generic type like :await _graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<YourClass>(query);